# How to get access to the variables in other method

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

I don't know how to explain that what i want correctly. Here is an example^

```
public void foo()
{
  StackFrame trace = new StackFrame(1);
  MethodBase method = trace.GetMethod(); //so, here we'll get bar-method info
  MthodBody body = method.GetMethodBody(); //and here we'll get bar-method body
  /*now i need get access to the local vars in bar
    i know about MethodBody.LocalVariables
    but i don't have any idea how i can get values of variables i and hello,
    that defined in bar-method. I think it may be possible if i'll get
    pointers to the vars,
    and then copy it with Marshal.Copy*/
}

public void bar()
{
  int i = 42;
  string hello = "Hello!";
  foo();
}
```

**PS** I hope my example was not terrible, and you understand what exactly i want.
**PPS** Excuse me for my bad-bad-bad English :)

Comment: What do you want to achieve? I don't know if you're going in the right direction.

Comment: I try create simply(or not) string formatter, like this: int i = 24; Format("i = {i}"); //will write i = 42

Comment: You can't get values from `LocalVariableInfo` instances.

Comment: I know it. And i was wrote: "I think it may be possible if i'll get pointers to the vars", but how to get it? Maybe that pointers contains in the IL-code of method(of course it local pointers)

Comment: still not sure of what you are trying to achieve - i read your comment above but if you can elaborate more it might help others to offer better suggestions. I am not even sure how well this will work in release mode.

Comment: Maybe it can help, maybe not, just some hint. C# 4.5 allows inlining, see MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining. If you will use it for foo(), it will be rolled into stack frame of bar() and it`s possibly better situation

Answer (score 0):

I guess, what you're really trying to do is some kind of method interception (I think you're trying to log parameters values or sth similar). Take a look at PostSharp http://www.sharpcrafters.com/blog/post/Day-7-Interception-Aspects-e28093-Part-1.aspx or [DynamicProxy](http://www.castleproject.org/dynamicproxy/index.html) in Castle Windsor.